# How do I rotate a head in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map, and I need a way to turn a head sideways. Any help? I've tried most things that a player would try, but nothing. Is there any way I can rotate the head?

Answer (score 3):

Heads face towards you when you place them. If you want to place a head face left, move to the left of the spot you're going to place it in before you place it. This is the same as almost anything else that has an orientation, so I assume you want to turn it around with commands.

To rotate a head with commands, the tag you need to edit is the "Rot" byte. For example, to make a head below you turn west, use this command:

```
/blockdata ~ ~-1 ~ {Rot:4b}
```

Here's a full list of what direction each number reperesents:

- 0: south
- 1: south-southwest
- 2: southwest
- 3: west-southwest
- 4: west
- 5: west-northwest
- 6: northwest
- 7: north-northwest
- 8: north
- 9: north-northeast
- 10: northeast
- 11: east-northeast
- 12: east
- 13: east-southeast
- 14: southeast
- 15: south-southeast

Comment: I mean I want to make the head turn sideways, as in on an angle.

Comment: @Anonymous That should be what this will do?

Comment: (e.x. I want to to turn the head on it's side)

Comment: @Anonymous Oh as in rolling it over? Not possible with head blocks. You could do it with an invisible armmorstand or another skin with the textures themselves rotated.